# How fundamental is the choice of title in a question on Math.SE?

Tags: discussion, answers, asking-questions, titles

When I'm trying to write a question I certainly make a lot of effort to be as clear as possible.

Certainly the hurry does not provide good advice and, several times in my specific case, I spend little time in giving only the essential elements to be able to get an answer.

> How much does the title of a question influence to get an answer or more answers?

Comment: Check the unanswered list

Comment: Whether the question gets an answer depends on the question, and people can only see the question if they click on it. So the title has to catch their interest. Tags help of course; folks will look for the tags they're interested in. But a question with a title like "How do I solve this?" is not doing itself any favours, which is a shame if the question itself is well written.

Comment: As Peter suggests, it is worth the time to consider a good title, and review it again after you write the question.  Also, titles should not repeat a tag: "Integration question" (which should be tagged as such, but such a title is far too general.)  Anything resembling: *NEED HELP ASA*, or even "Please Help me" will likely not have a chance.   It's far easier to list what not to write as a title.  Just remember, the title is the first thing users see, and what do you most what to share to inform users about your specific question.

Comment: Your title is an advertisement for the question.  You are hoping to attract people who can answer to click through and read the question.  Having a good title can suggest that you gave thought to the question, so make it more attractive to readers.

Comment: @Ross Millikan I Hope to do always the best for my students and to have answers. No attract because i not want upvotes but explanations on inspiegabile downvotes

Comment: Probably a lot, you want a title to invite askers to answer your question while also making the title as useful as possible for future question askers.

Comment: Just a note: '[inspiegabile](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34160/how-fundamental-is-the-choice-of-title-in-a-question-on-math-se#comment157934_34160)' in English is '[inexplicable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inexplicable)'.

Comment: @frogeyedpeas I agree with your thoughts. I like knowledge especially about topics I haven't covered well or don't know exist. As for positive votes I don't ask for anything but you can personally check on TeX.SE. or with gurus using LaTeX if I ask for votes from anyone. Never done. I don't like gratuitous nastiness.

Comment: @LSpice I didn't use a translator and have Italianized the word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on who you want to attract. Not everybody will go to a "help me" title. Typically , they either need knowledge about the area used to solve the question, or they would waste their time by looking at the question. Not everybody has deep knowledge in all areas, so more advanced question would be skippable. However , if they don't know what's required by the title, they may be forced to look at the question, if they want to see if they have the knowledge required. Proper tagging will still matter, but if the title fits the body of the question, retagging to an appropriate tag isn't all that hard.

Comment: I thank you for your kindness and for the opportunity to know also your viewpoint.